# Minimizing Evolution to the tray

Tags: evolution, system-tray

How do I minimize Evolution to its tray icon?

I've installed evolution-indicator, and it does show evolution under the messaging menu, but I have no idea how to minimize it.

I've installed Evolution-Tray (Plugin) from source, but it doesn't work (Doesn't show any icon, Evolution does nothing when minimized).

**Edit**: I would like to avoid AllTray if possible.

Comment: Evolution Tray works if you're running Gnome on Xorg session.

Answer (score 2):

You can use compiz to hide minimized evolution window and then messaging menu to maximize again.

You need compiz config settings manager and in Window Rules add:

Skip Taskbar: (class=Evolution ) & state=hidden
and
Skip Pager: (class=Evolution ) & state=hidden

and now Evolution only appears whem maximized in launcher and pager.

Answer (score 0):

I used [Minimize to Tray](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1750/minimize-to-tray/) on Ubuntu 19.04 and Evolution 3.32.1. More info can be found on the github [page](https://github.com/oae/gnome-shell-minimize-to-tray).

Once I added the extension, I could add Evolution using Gnome-Tweaks. I also ran the following to have it functional:

```
sudo apt install xdotool
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Evolution with i3 window manager. While googling for options I've got to this thread. My answer is not directly Ubuntu oriented, but I'd like to share my solution here, as it might be applied also to Ubuntu users.

I developed a simple python based solution that allows hiding any app to the tray. It uses i3 scratchpad workspace under the hood.

[i3-appvindicator](https://github.com/vindex10/i3-appvindicator/)

After installation, you can run:

```
i3-appvindicator -t 'Evolution Tray' -i 'evolution-mail' 'class="Evolution"'
```

and the tray icon should show up. Middle click will toggle app show/hide.